# htaccess getting subdomain in subdirectory [Apache 2.2.27]

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a dynamic subdomain setup on my server with

> *.example.com=>example.com/page.php?pageDetailId=[*]

My `.htaccess` :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^([w]{3,3}[.]{1,1}){0,1}example.com$
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([0-9a-zA-Z-]*)[.]example.com$
    RewriteRule ^$ page.php?pageDetailId=%1 [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

This works fine when I open `abc.example.com` I get the abc in `page.php`.

Now I have a subdirectory as `example.com/student/*` Now I want that subdomain value in `student/*` too. Especially, `student/MyCourse.php`. How to achieve it?

My new `.htaccess` :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^([w]{3,3}[.]{1,1}){0,1}example.com$
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([0-9a-zA-Z-]*)[.]example.com$
    RewriteRule ^$ page.php?pageDetailId=%1 [NC,L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^([w]{3,3}[.]{1,1}){0,1}example.com$
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([0-9a-zA-Z-]*)[.]example.com$
    RewriteRule ^/student/MyCourse.php$ /student/MyCourse.php?pageDetailId=gateonline [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by placing one more `.htaccess` in the subdirectory student as :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^([w]{3,3}[.]{1,1}){0,1}arcanemind.com$
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([0-9a-zA-Z-]*)[.]arcanemind.com$
    RewriteRule ^MyCourse.php$ MyCourse.php?pageDetailId=%1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Still I will appreciate if anyone has a way to use regex and pass the variable in all files in the subdirectory.